# How to use a String in an Entity class hash code?

Tags: java, sql, persistence, entity, hashcode

I'm making a web app that queries an SQL db.  I'm under the impression that I need to use entity classes and facade classes to allow persistence - across the whole site.  The entity class templates have hashcodes and 1.) Im not sure if I need them and 2.) If I do, they want int's but all I have are String so, how to convert them to int and then back to String?  Because I need the String value to appear on the site and the hash wants int's.

heres the code (imports have been remove to protect the innocent...):

```
@Embeddable
public class ComputerOwnersPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional=false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="Computer_Name")
    private int computerNameId;
    @Basic(optional=false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="User_ID")
    private int userId;

    public ComputerOwnersPK() {
    }

    public ComputerOwnersPK(int computerNameId,int userId) {
        this.computerNameId=computerNameId;
        this.userId=userId;
    }

    public int getComputerNameId() {
        return computerNameId;
    }

    public void setComputerNameId(int computerNameId) {
        this.computerNameId=computerNameId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId=userId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash=0;
        hash+=(int) computerNameId;
        hash+=(int) userId;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if(!(object instanceof ComputerOwnersPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        ComputerOwnersPK other=(ComputerOwnersPK) object;
        if(this.computerNameId!=other.userId) {
            return false;
        }
        if(this.userId!=other.userId) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.ComputerOwnersPK[ computerNameId="+computerNameId+", userId="+userId+" ]";
    }
}
```

Comment: To use objects as part of a `hashCode()` use their own `hashCode()`, e.g. `hash += str.hashCode();`

Comment: where are the `String`? I just see `int`

Comment: right, they are string but in the code -in order to remove errors - they are int's but, they are actuallly Strings...

Comment: @miorel  like this???   hash+=str.hashCode(computerNameId);

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I'm assuming you want computerNameId and userId to be Strings in your mapping and you have them mapped to ints because you don't know how to do the hashcode stuff.

In your hashCode method you should be able to concatenate the strings and then call hashcode on them.  Very similar to what you are already doing.

```
private String computerNameId;
private String userId;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // concatenate the interesting string fields 
    // and take the hashcode of the resulting String
    return (computerNameId + userId).hashCode();
}
```

Make sure in your equals method you also change from `!=` operators to `!.equals` method call for checking equality.  Finally make sure you are keeping the [contract between equals and hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or you could be in for some nasty surprises.  Two objects that are equal must also have the same hashCode.  Two objects that have the same hashCode may or may not be equal.

Comment: well.. the first part seems to work however, changing != to !.equals is not....also, im wondering if I'm going to be able to retain the original value of the two Strings?  Is there another way to use persistence without entity classes??

Comment: by `!.equals` I meant something like `if (!computeNameId.equals(other.computerNameId)`.  You don't have to use entities. You could go with pure JDBC, where you issue plain SQL and deal with the result set yourself, manually mapping columns in the result to whatever java properties/variables you want.